# Crystal Reports: auto column width

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I created a report using Crystal Reports 11 and trying to display it in my ASP.NET application using CrystalReportViewer. My report is just a table with several columns and header row. The problem is that when text exceeds cell's width, it overlaps the next cell. What I'm trying to achieve is that column width is automatically adjusted to accommodate the longest text in the column (just like normal HTML tables do). Please help me, I can't believe this common thing is so hard to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know Crystal only allows you automatically expand a field vertically not horizontally.

To automatically increase the size of a field vertically you need to:

- Right click the field and select "Format Text"
- Select the "Common" tab
- Ensure the "Can Grow" check box is checked.
- Enter a value in the "Maximum number of lines box" (Leave at 0 for unlimited growth)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this, it works, the text is wrapped to the next line. However, the border's height is as if it has only one line of text. Also, other cells in the row don't stretch. Could you please tell if there is a way to tell the border of all cells in the row to stretch according to the biggest cell?

Comment: @duke84 - If you want to auto grow all other fields to match the maximum height of a field then no, you can't do this.  Are you able to post a screen print of what it looks like now and how you would like it to look?

Comment: @Barry - Here is a screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14931527/Screen%20shot%202010-11-15%20at%201.43.12%20PM.png .

Comment: @duke84 - how have you put a border around that?  Have you set in `Format Text` > `Borders`?

Comment: @Barry - yes, I added border in the Format Text > Borders, however, the border didn't appear, so I had to add css style: <code>.crystalstyle div.rowColumn
{
 border:1px solid #000000;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
</code>

Comment: @duke84 - adding the borders via the Format Text should work correctly.  The reason why it doesn't work now is because you are hard coding the height within the CSS.  You should avoid doing this.

Comment: @Barry - it doesn't show borders nor backgrounds at all. Here is screenshot of report in the reports designer: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14931527/Screen%20shot%202010-11-15%20at%206.49.17%20PM.png and how the CrystalReportViewer renders it if I apply no additional styles: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14931527/Screen%20shot%202010-11-15%20at%206.51.03%20PM.png . Do you know why this happens?

Comment: I fixed this by removing the DOCTYPE from the page

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically increase the size of the field vertically. Then the data will display in several rows if the field length is not enough.

1. First Right Click on the field that you want to resize.
2. Then select the "Format Text"
3. Select the "Common" tab.
4. Then put a tick on the "Can Grow" Check Box.
5. If you need minimum number of lines enter value for the "Maximum
   number of lines box".
6. If you need to grow it unlimitedly then leave it as 0

Hope this will help for you.